# Cypress is not clicking on element

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

```
describe('(F<->C) switching', function() {
it("(F<->C) swithing", function() {
    cy.visit('https://weather.com')
    cy.get('.styles__borderLeft__2zhrE').contains('°C')
    cy.get('.styles__button__1Rnmk').first().click()
   })
})
```

This is such a simple code, but it doesn't click on button for some reason. Do you have any ideas why? You can check this code on and i dont understand whats wrong [Weather.com](https://weather.com)

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Your test passes here. I am using Cypress 3.6.1 for this test. But the initial load takes very long. As @AlapanDas already mentioned, it would be good if you can post your error message.

Comment: @AlapanDas that is the main problem. There is no errors it just dont click on element.

Comment: @MikitaKazlouski Can you try with `cy.get('.styles__button__1Rnmk', {timeout: 5000}).first().click({force: true)`

Answer (score -1):

Force the event click by using .click({ force: true })

See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#forcing